# Keyboard not hiding in iOS 6

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I'm pushing a view controller to a navigation controller and in iOS 7 when that happens the keyboard automatically hides.

However, in iOS 6, it does not. I also can't get it to go away with `[self.view endEditing:YES];`.

EDIT: In the preceding view controller, once the keyboard is brought up, it does not go away in that view controller with `[self.view endEditing:YES]` either.

Comment: Try calling `resignFirstResponder` on the `UITextField` responsible of this before pushing your view controller?

Comment: Did you use `UITextField` ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using `UITextField`.

I commented out the only `becomeFirstResponder` in the `UITextField` in the view previous to pushing my view and I also added a `resignFirstResponder` for every `UITextField` but I still cannot get the keyboard to dismiss.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

    [self performSelector:@selector(resignFirstResponder) onChildrenOfView:self.view];

}

-(void)performSelector:(SEL)selector onChildrenOfView:(UIView*)view{

    for ( UIView * subView in view.subviews ) {

        if ( [subView respondsToSelector:selector] ) {
            [subView performSelector:selector];
        }

        if ( [subView isKindOfClass:[UIView class]] ) {
            [self performSelector:selector onChildrenOfView:subView];
        }

    }

}
```

Sorry if it's a little verbose.

Comment: In the preceding view controller, once I bring the keyboard up, I cannot hide it also.